# Uploading and uploaded file without saving with python requests

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a web server that acts as a proxy between users and a file server. Users can upload their files to my web server and I upload them to the file server. I want to be able to do this without saving the temp uploaded file but every time I get unexpected end of file error from the file server. This is my code (I'm using django rest framework for my APIs).

```
headers = {"content-type":"multipart/form; boundary={}".format(uuid.uuid4().hex)}
files = []
for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
    files.append((f.name, open(f.file.name,'rb'), f.content_type))
files_dict = {'file': files}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `content-type` header in your request. There is no need to manually set `multipart/form` and `boundary` if you're using `files` argument from `requests`. That is why you're getting unexpected end of file error. Try sending your request without that header.

```
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```